# Grouped UITableView Interface Builder Examples/Tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I'm having an immense amount of trouble figuring out how to populate a Grouped UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. Could anyone point me towards a tutorial on how one might do this? Or does anyone have an example of what a cellForRowAtIndexPath method would look like when creating a Grouped UITableView with custom UITableViewCells?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some guidelines:

Each of your group in grouped UITableView is a section. Then the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (indexPath.section == 0) {
      // Here is first group
      if (indexPath.row == 0) {
         // Here is first row in a first group 
      }
   }
}
```

I hope that this makes sense for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can browse this [TableViewSuite sample codes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318).