# iOS white background behind settings controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

Is there a control that can achieve the appearance that is in this image?

It looks like some special single round cornered table cell a UISlider embedded in it.

What I am wondering is it really a table cell, it seems overkill to do this. Is it possible there is something in iOS to achieve this without using an UIimage as a background.

Thanks,
-Code

[image]

Comment: I use this approach of Grouped Table View Cells in many cases where there are SEVERAL (not just one) elements on the screen, one for each line. It simplifies the creation of this set of elements - However just for one or two I agree, there is no real reason to use table view cell - it just complicates the code.

Comment: Note that even a table view with one grouped section means you're not creating a custom control - it's still coded for you.  By using the standard iOS controls you also benefit from enhancements and fixes going forward.  As a basic rule, I only customize if I really *need* a custom look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [grouped table view section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748544/grouped-uitableview-interface-builder-examples-tutorial) with one view in it.  That [custom table view cell](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder) in the grouped table view section looks to have a UISlider with a UILabel on either side of it.

As a general rule, you should always lean toward using the standard built in controls unless you really need a custom look.

See the third image here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Also: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html

From that link:

> **Grouped Table Views**
>
> A grouped table view also displays a list of
>   information, but it groups related rows in visually distinct sections.
>   As shown in Figure 1-4, each section has rounded corners and by
>   default appears against a bluish-gray background. Each section may
>   have text or an image for its header or footer to provide some context
>   or summary for the section. A grouped table works especially well for
>   displaying the most detailed information in a data hierarchy. It
>   allows you to separate details into conceptual groups and provide
>   contextual information to help users understand it quickly.